# Multiple textviews displaying Volley response getting blank: Android

Tags: android, json, textview, android-volley

I am having an app that shows a list of several companies with their branches.
I am using volley to fetch and display the business hours of each of the company.
The business hours are shown alright when there is a single branch but in the case of companies with multiple branches, the business hours are blank except for the last one.
I am getting all the details correct on logging but not in layout.

Below is my code for the volley request,

```
    public void getData(final RelativeLayout timeLayoutCollapse, final RelativeLayout timeLayout, final int) {


    //URL for fetching the branch time from the server.
    String url = context.getString(site_url) + "branch_time.cfc?method=branchtime&branchid=" + dBranchID;
    Log.d(url, "this is urlllll");

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
               // Log.d(String.valueOf(response), "reqqqqqqqqq");


                showJSON(response, timeLayoutCollapse, timeLayout);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        timeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

I am calling the getData() method from,

```
final int size = branchesList.size();
      if (size >= 2) {
companyName.setText(branchesList.get(i).getBranchName());
businessHours.setText(branchesList.get(i).getBranchName() + " Business Hours:");
   Log.d(String.valueOf(bid), "BARCHIDDDD");
   Log.d(branchesList.get(i).getBranchName(), "LIST BRANCH NEWWWWWWW");
   timeLayoutCollapse.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   getData(timeLayoutCollapse, timeLayout);
}
```

The JSON parsing and displaying is done in,

```
    public void showJSON(final String response, RelativeLayout timeLayoutCollapse, RelativeLayout timeLayout) {

         JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("DATA");

        final int numberOfItemsInBranch = result.length();

        Log.d(String.valueOf(result),"checcccckkkkkk");

            timeStatus.setText("business hours are ");
            currentStatus.setText("unknown");
```

The data in logs is such as,

```
D/0: LOPPPPPPPPPP
D/AAA Branch: LIST BRANCH NAMEEEEEEE
D/BBB: locaaattiiooon
D/0: this is url with BRANCHH
D/http://the url/FOLDER/branch_time.cfc?method=branchtime&branchid=0: this   is urlllll
D/1758: BARCHIDDDD
D/CCCCCC: LIST BRANCH NEWWWWWWW
D/1758: this is url with BRANCHH
D/http://the url/FOLDER/branch_time.cfc?method=branchtime&branchid=1758: this is url
```

The log data for the server response,

```
[D/[[670,1758,1671,"08:00","08:00","08:00","08:00","08:00","09:00","Closed","17:00","17:00","17checcccckkkkkk
```

Displaying the data in the text view as

```
        companyTime1.setText(SUN_O + '-' + SUN_C);
        companyTime2.setText(MON_O + '-' + MON_C);
```

where,

```
            MON_O = companyData.getString(3);
            MON_C = companyData.getString(10);

            SUN_O = companyData.getString(9);
            SUN_C = companyData.getString(16);
```

I am getting all the required data in logs but while displaying them the textview texts are getting blank.
I am quite new to android and cannot figure a way out of this. Please, can anyone help?

Comment: Where is your log for `Log.d(String.valueOf(result),"checcccckkkkkk");`?? Can you please post the JSON response?

Comment: Please see the edit. @FAT

Comment: From where you are setting data to TextView? can you post details code?

Comment: @FAT Can you please check the code now?

Comment: @FAT Did u get a chance to have a look at my code. I am still facing this issue and can't find a way out of it.

Answer (score 0):

@Deepak You are updating the same views with different data and thus the last data from `JSONArray` gets show up. You need to display it in listView  or `RecyclerView`.

Comment: This should be a comment ! You have enough reputation to post as a comment.

Comment: Does that matter?

Comment: So can you tell ?

Comment: More than 6 years

Comment: Omg ! This is really good yar :) Damn good. I have less than yours

Comment: @Aditi I don't want to use listview or RecylerView. Isn't there any way to stop the overriding using the existing views.